# RepositoryItemComboBox Clears item When not in focus

Tags: combobox, repository, devexpress

So Basically i created 7 columns `[Particular] ,[Category] ,[Warranty] ,[Name] [Description] ,[Stocks],[Orders]` `[Particular] ,[Category]` and `[Warranty]` columns are created using `DataTable` and was in the `Form_load Event`

```
Dim tbl As New DataTable
        tbl.Columns.Add("Particular")
        tbl.Columns.Add("Category")
        tbl.Columns.Add("Warranty")
        tbl.Rows.Add("Select Particular", "Select Category", "Select Warranty")
        GridControl.DataSource = dtbl
```

the 4 remaining Columns are created using `UnBoundColumnData` this columns will receive the Excel files that i am importing

How i created the columns,and can also be located in `Form_Load event`

```
Dim Fields() As String = {"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "STOCK", "ORDERED"}
        Dim View As ColumnView = GridControl1.MainView
        Dim gc3 As New GridColumn
        For i As Integer = 0 To Fields.Length - 1
            gc3 = GridView1.Columns.AddField(Fields(i))
            gc3.VisibleIndex = View.Columns.Count
            gc3.UnboundType = UnboundColumnType.String
        Next
```

Then I created the `RepositoryItemComboBox` for the Particular-Category-Warranty column and is inside the `GridView1_CustomRowCellEdit Event`

```
 Dim rcb As RepositoryItemComboBox
        rcb = New RepositoryItemComboBox
        rcb.Items.Add("AA")
        rcb.Items.Add("BB")
        rcb.Items.Add("CC")
        GridView1.Columns("Particular").ColumnEdit = rcb
```

This populates the Particular Column and makes the `ColumnEdit = RepositoryItemComboBox`

Now when i load the Form without Importing the Excel files just yet the values inside the `[Particular]` column stays even when i focus to different rows. But when i started importing the excel files then try to select an item from the `RepositoryItemComboBox` it now clears the Value when i focus to different Rows

I really need some help with this one because i have no idea on how to keep those values. Thank you

Comment: How do you load from Excel? Do you set DataSource? If so, you have a new DataSource with only 4 columns.

Comment: yes im using OleDbConnection to Load the Excel File Then passed to an OleDbDataAdapter and is .Fill by a DataSet lastly calling it by GridControl.Datasource = DataSource.Tables(0). Can you help me with this problem Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add unbound colums after loading data from Excel.

```
private void FillExcelToGrid() {
   var tbl = GetExcelAsDataTable(); // this method wraps your existing code, you return the datatabele
   tbl.Columns.Add("Particular")
   tbl.Columns.Add("Category")
   tbl.Columns.Add("Warranty")

   for (var ii = 0; ii < tbl.Rows.Count; ii++) {
     tbl.Rows[ii]["Particular"] = "Select Particular";
     tbl.Rows[ii]["Category"] = "Select Category";
     tbl.Rows[ii]["Warranty"] = "Select Warranty";
   }
   GridControl.DataSource = tbl;
}
```

Comment: so basically i have to add the columns after importing the excel file so i should put it in a button instead of loading it in the form_load event..Thank you you have been Helpful